# What kind of weapons should be sent up with space colonists?

Tags: weapons, space-colonization

On a colonization effort to a Goldilocks planet with known dangers on par with bears and wolves, it makes sense for an organization to send weapons for protection, hunting, and keeping order.

I know that the Russians have a 9mm on their Soyuz capsule, in case they land in a place with wild animals. It seems to me that it's quite reasonable for an space faring organization to send colonists up with similar protections.

On a space colonization mission, what kind of weapons might NASA want to equip the colonists with?

Comment: Questions of the form "What should I do?" are often closed as off topic because they are too story based.

Comment: @sphennings Sorry, I'm just being cheeky, I'm more asking what NASA might want to send with astronauts on such a mission

Comment: Since they are worried about stuff on another planet the weapon of choice on this planet would be your best bet.

Comment: By the time our species gets around to colonizing extrasolar planets, Earthlike or not, NASA will probably not exist. Sufficient social, political or organizational change will have taken place, for it to be gone. This is a way of saying it won't be NASA equipping colonists with weapons. Not unless, we discover cheap interstellar travel technology in the next few decades.

Comment: Look up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocene_extinction#Megafaunal_extinction It seems that cavemen hunted quite many big game, thus on a virgin planet you should expect some multi tone animals. If cavemen with spearthrowers were able to exterminate them, they are actually not so impressive fighters, nevertheless taking weapon that would be an overkill by Earth standards is advised. Because dragging multi types of ammo is a logistic nightmare, I suggest some small caliber, hollow point bullets with semi automatic fire.

Comment: The Ancestors had a huge advantage in they were born and raises as hunter-gatherers, hunting animals with spears, arrows and other weapons was a way of life. Using any sort of weapon requires training and practice, for the Ancestors this would literally be a daily occurrence, since missing your target could mean death by mauling or starvation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since weight is always an issue in space travel, any weapon you select will have a limited supply of ammo.  This elevates non-firearms such as swords, bows and crossbows because they either do not need ammo or their ammo can be fashioned from natural resources readily available on the target planet.

Since Crossbow bolts require less craftsmanship than arrows, I would opt for an aluminum crossbow with several replacements of all parts which may wear out.  I would also take one or more swords, chosen to maximize reach within whatever weight limits I must obey.

I would also take casting supplies for arrow heads and crossbow bolts.  That way more weapons can be created from mined metal ores and unused ship parts.

And of course, I would bring lots of weapons creation knowledge in the form of e-books and digital videos, so that once planet-side, a forge can be set up for creating larger blades, more crossbows and simple firearms.

Comment: Casting swords is bad idea, casting daggers is probably even worse. Only arrow heads and boltscan realistically be cast and be functional. You don't need sword that will break the first time you hit something with it, do you? Also, why swords when colonist will need machetes anyway and machete can be used as a weapon? It works well as dusack and can be made to be usable as a "hunting sword".

Comment: Thanks @Molot, I will edit my answer with the information you have provided.

Comment: By the way, if they can smelt iron, they will be able to *forge* blades.

Comment: If these people can reliably take on a bear with a sword, they don't really need anything but improvised weapons.

Comment: Humans are pack hunters!  The bear won't be up against one sword.

Comment: Ammunition for firearms can also be fashioned from the natural resources readily available on the target planet. Brass, lead, nitrocellulose, and any number of chemicals for primers.

Comment: @John hunting swords were used to finish game and save munition, to defend against game not as dead as you thought it to be etc. with a nice option to be use as machete by a gentleman who can be seen with a sword but not with peasant tool. Hunting with swords only was never a thing.

Comment: Royalty in Mycenaean times used spears to hunt lions, bulls and wild boars, not swords. Of course they were usually armoured and protected by shields as well.....

Answer (score 5):

I would think that the simple answer is exactly the same sort of weapon that you'd take with you on Earth, perhaps a slightly more advanced version to make it a little more lightweight.

If you're just planning on keeping bears and wolves (or similar aliens) at bay then a .45 or similar handgun and 100-odd rounds of ammunition per colonist would do the trick at a total weight of 3-4kg each.

For hunting, you might want to go a little bigger, such as a rifle.

Comment: Plus if you are colonizing another planet you should have some pretty complex chemical fabrication technology along, making gunpowder is not that hard, they should have the tech to make explosives anyway. Considering how valuable your livestock will be, the extra weight of some high powered firearms is completely justified.

Comment: Perhaps for drama, yes weapons make a better story. But I think if you are planning well ahead, non-lethal methods should keep the animals at bay in most cases. Pepper, olfactory, audio, fences...

Comment: Assuming your alien animals are sensitive to pepper, smell or sounds..

Comment: consider an air rifle for the most general firearm, much easier to make ammunition for and pressurizing gas technology would be fairly omnipresent in their equipment.There are some very high power air rifles today, the largest gunes should be powder weapon but the small common ones could air rifles. as a bonus they can be loaded with tranquilizer darts for flexibility. The .303 range air guns will perform well for what you describe. and ammunition is really easy to make, all you need is casting technology.

Answer (score 5):

There are any number of purpose built [survival rifles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Survival_rifles) and shotguns (and both) to choose from. These are intended for downed aircrews in hostile territory to hunt small and medium game, as well as self-defense in a pinch. They're designed to be light, compact, durable, and easy to use. These are all desirable for a hunting weapon to be shipped on a colony ship where space and weight are a premium.

The current version in US Air Force service is the [AR-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armalite_AR-7).

[image]

Its a magazine fed [simple blowback semi-automatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowback_(firearms)#Simple_blowback) rifle. It weighs just over 1kg, and with the barrel removed is about half a meter long. All parts store in the stock, and it will float. It has a peep sight making it very easy to aim.

The AR-7 fires [.22 Long Rifle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.22_Long_Rifle), but [.22 Hornet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.22_Hornet) might be more desirable for a space colony. Both have minimal recoil, and are very quiet making them very forgiving for an untrained shooter.

While both fire the same 3 gram projectile, .22 Hornet's muzzle velocity is almost 2.5 faster with 7 times the kinetic energy. The resulting flatter trajectory makes it easier to aim. And the additional energy makes it effective against medium game such as turkeys, pigs, and goats.

.22 Hornet is about twice the size and weight of .22 LR meaning you can carry half as much. This is offset because .22 Hornet is [centerfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centerfire_ammunition) and the brass case can be reloaded. .22 LR is a [rimfire cartridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rimfire_(firearms)) and it cannot be reloaded. The colonists can save weight by carrying a limited amount of brass cases, and an extra supply of gunpowder, projectiles, and primers to reload them. Eventually they'd manufacture their own, this is late-19th century technology.

Unlike fancy sci-fi weapons, the colonists will be able to maintain this weapon and manufacture ammunition without high-tech facilities.

This should be sufficient for day-to-day pest control, hunting, and self-defense. Packing many very light survival rifles means putting more weapons in the hands of more colonists. A handful of larger, heavier weapons would be on hand to deal with larger threats should they appear.

Comment: While this is actually a great rifle, even a .22 Hornet round is not going to do much against a charging bear. If you are really lucky, it will bleed out after it has mauled you to death.....

Comment: @Thucydides As I said at the bottom, it's a trade off. You could bring .30-06, but that's more weight, more space meaning less guns, less ammo. Such a powerful round needs more training to be used effectively. It's more weight for colonists to hump around the wilderness. If the planet is like ours, large fauna are rare, not particularly aggressive, and afraid of loud noises; you don't have to shoot them. Rather than giving a few people a rifle that's overpowered for most of their needs, give more a rifle better suited for day-to-day, with more ammo. Have a few full power rifles for a militia.

Comment: The proper trade off needs to take the projected target into consideration. Bears often need multiple hits from full sized rifle rounds to stop them, so smaller and less powerful rounds are simply not going to do. An AR-15 will be ineffective with a Remington .223, and even an M-16 fired on automatic might not deliver enough lethal force to kill the bear before it reaches you.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is finally a great time to use laser pistols.  While lasers may be not too useful on earth with limited metals in a space colony they could be of great aid.

The pistols could be plugged into the main power cell each colonist caries that powers everything from his life support system, communication, and other electronics.  This may give only a few shots before the batteries are drained but I am hoping by the time we are colonising space with wild animals we would have better batteries.

Back at the base the solar panels can recharge the batteries at almost no cost.  And if no wild animals are encountered on the planet the extra battery power each colonist caries may come into play for any other hazard the planet may have

Comment: Sorry, but I am not agree with your answer (I don't put a -1). A portable  laser is almost impossible, a laser of such size would only "burn" the flesh of an animal and not make a hole (wolf won't die). I think it would be better to have **very powerful flashlights capable of blind (at least temporaly) the target".

Comment: @EnderLook We are landing colonists on an exoplanet.  I think we can safely assume anything that currently takes up a warehouse can fit in a pocket

Comment: @EnderLook in fact, lasers, if powerful enough, are a good way to blind a target. It's not really plausible today to have colonists packing blaster pistols that fire hundreds of flesh-searing shots without a recharge, but it's much more plausible for them to carry something that can burn a retina or two.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, I was saying that, it would be better has some very powerful flashlight to blind the target. I didn't say a laser because that is a very focus point of light and it would be dificult to target an eye but a powerful spotlight could blind temporaly a target without much acuracy.

Comment: @EnderLook That being said, I think the pain from having your flesh burned in a completely unknown and uncomprehensible way would give most animals pause.

Comment: @Doomfrost I don't know how it is written in English but animal had a lot of hair in their bodies, you have right, they would burn a lot and "easy".

Comment: @EnderLook Just thought about armadillos though, they'd probably be impervious to anything but prolonged laser fire (depending on how thick their bone plates are). Then again, against a flesh eating giant alien armadillobear any kinetic small arms fire is probably pointless as well.

Answer (score 3):

Based off the [lasers idea](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/85437/35041) from Andrey I get these ideas:

## Flashlights

A flashlight use batteries to work (rechargeable) and also they are easy to use: you only have to target their eyes.
My idea is to have very powerful flashlights capable of blinding (at least temporarily) the enemy. Wolves and other kinds of animals would be scared if the see a very powerful light.
On the market we already have flashlights of several thousand of lumens and they are able to damage eyes, so it would pretty easy for NASA increase the power and use a zoom to blind targets.

## Electroshock

You can use [electroshock weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon), they use power not ammo! And like flashlights using them in a proper way you can not hurt the target! (If you want you can kill them when they are paralyzed...).
I think that the best of electroshock is they has a wide variety of weapons:

- [Stun belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon#Stun_belts) for prisoners.
- [Electric shock prods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon#Electric_shock_prods) for close combat.
- [Stun shield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon#Stun_shields) I didn't know they exist! Defensive and tactic at the same time.
- [Taser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taser) for short and mid range.
- [Compact stun gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroshock_weapon#Compact_stun_guns), small and discreet.

I also found [electrified water cannon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_cannon#Electrified_water_cannon) but they are experimental. Maybe you could adapt a electricity source to a water gun. There I also found a machine capable of cutting a person at half using a water stream but I don't think that that machine would be portable.

Answer (score 2):

The nature of the threat determines the nature of the weapons, but you should also consider the ability of the colonists to use these weapons. Pistols are notoriously difficult to use without constant practice (even military issue 9mm weapons), and larger calibre like .45 ACP, 10mm or .40 cal are generally even harder for untrained people to use properly. The colonists can make a lot of noise, but will generally miss moving targets even at point blank range.

[image]

*Few movies ever depict proper shooting stances*

Rifles are somewhat better, since their size makes the user pay more attention to how they hold them, and the mass of a rifle generally absorbs more of the recoil force the shooter experiences. However, practice and training are needed to be effective with a rifle, especially as the range increases or trying to engage a moving target. Another consideration is the calibre of the round. For targets that are the analogues of wolves and bears, rifles in the .30 cal, .303 or 7.62 X 51 range are needed to provide enough power to effectively take out the target. Smaller weapons like an AR-15 using 5.56 X 45 (Remington .223) simply won't have sufficient stopping power, and dealing with angry, injured animals is something you best avoid.

The best compromise might be shotguns. A 12 gauge shotgun firing .00 magnum shot will provide sufficient range and stopping power for even large predators, plus the ability of the shotgun to provide a "pattern" ensures that it is easier to hit even difficult targets even with a less trained shooter. Using semi automatic shotguns would be preferred, since we don't want to risk a colonist jamming or misloading a shotgun by "short stroking" the pump action, and a "break" action shotgun only has 2 rounds, when you might need more. The size and weight of a shotgun absorbs some of the recoil, while at the same time providing a "secondary" weapon since you can use it as a club at short range if needed. In WWI, the USMC used the [Winchester Model 1897 "trench gun"](http://www.guns.com/2013/02/26/1897-winchester-trench-gun/) with devastating effect. The thing even came with a huge sword bayonet.

[image]

*Winchester Model 1897 w bayonet*

So unless the colonists are guarded by a trained military or PMC security force trained in the use of firearms and combat, or have all received extensive training *and* are avid hunters, using shotguns is probably the best way to provide security against carnivorous animals. To increase effectiveness, the shotguns need proper reflex sights which allow the shooter to quickly pick up targets and instinctively shoot with both eyes open.

[image]

*Shotgun with reflex sight mounted*

Comment: Bearing in mind that the biggest predators in Earth history would be things like T-Rexes, roughly the size of African Bull elephants, would this need bigger guns.. And it's possible that a planet with lower surface gravity would allow for even bigger animals.

Comment: The OP specifically said "Bears and Wolves", so 00 Magnum shot or 7.62 X 51 analogues are the proper range of calibres to meet the threat. If you are hunting elephant sized game, then much larger and more powerful rounds are called for, like the .458 magnum Winchester. Since a T-Rex is more likely to be hunting *you*, you might consider defense in the form of a .50 cal (especially an HMG) or even a grenade launcher like the 6 shot Milker MGL the USMC use for maximum firepower.